# reset a maximum value within a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify how many times values exceed the previous input. the following code works for 1,7,9,0 (two times 7, exceeds 1, 9 exceeds 7), but fails on 1,5,2,4,3,0. I get that this is because I set the maximum to 5 and of course 2 and 4 are less than 5. I cannot figure out what to do to "reset" maximum back to 1

```
a = int(input())
counter = 0
highest = 1
while a != 0:
    if a > highest:
        highest = a
        counter += 1
    a=int(input())

# need to reset highest to next input of 'a'
print(counter)
```

Grateful for your patience. Still an oldie seeing whether I am brain-dead yet. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just don't see it. Also the course I am following intimates that I can't use anything but if, else, while, no lists or anything

Comment: what is your expected output? what "fails"? sounds OK to me.

Comment: for the first example, the code should return 2 because , 7 is higher than 1 and 9 is higher than 7. The second example returns 1 , only counts five higher than one: because maximum gets set to five, the fact that 4 is higher than 2 is not counted. I am looking for a way that maximum gets reset after counting the first instance, so that 4 will be recognised as higher than 2, and the count returned is 2 and not 1

Comment: OK managed to resolve by inserting  an elif clause: elif a < highest: highest = a,  which resets a lower value to the new maximum. I am sure that there is a better(cleverer) way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

```
first_num = int(input())
incremental_count = 0
while first_numv != 0:
    second_num = int(input())
    if second_num != 0 and first_num < second_num:
        incremental_count += 1
    first_num = second_num
print(incremental_count)
```

Once I solved it my way, this was the answer given which is cleverer and simpler!